# How detect MongoDB reconnection for replica set

Tags: node.js, mongodb

If I try to register for the event 'reconnect' in a MongoDB replicaset:

```
db.on('reconnect', () => console.log('Reconnected'));
```

I receive a deprecation warning as:

```
DeprecationWarning: The `reconnect` event is no longer supported by the unified topology
```

How can I handle a case of lost MongoDB connection (all servers in the replica set) but I want to be notified of servers availability status (when at least one server become again available)?
Suppose to handle this in a Node app with MongoDB native drivers.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the spec regarding the [unified topology](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/unified-topology/), we can find the following section:

> The unified topology is the first step in a paradigm shift away from a
> concept of “connecting” to a MongoDB deployment using a connect
> method. Consider for a moment what it means to be connected to a
> replica set: do we trigger this state when connected to a primary? A
> primary and one secondary? When connected to all known nodes? It’s
> unclear whether its possible to answer this without introducing
> something like a ReadPreference parameter to the connect method. At
> this point “connecting” is just one half of “operation execution” -
> you pass a ReadPreference in, and await a selectable server for the
> operation, now we’re connected!

There are, however, new events you can listen to and that might be useful for your usecase -> see [this](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/management/sdam-monitoring/) for more information.